# Is Georgia Coffee Sweet?

Tags: flavor

So they sell these MAX Coffees in Japan, and I've heard they're super sweet. Do such sort of sweet coffee actually exist (I've been told it's been like coffee flavored condensed milk). MAX Coffee is supposedly Georgia Coffee, so I wonder if all Georgia coffees are also sweet?

Answer (score 2):

Georgia coffee has both canned coffee and plastic bottle coffees. Max comes in both styles and it is VERY SWEET.
Not all coffees in Japan are sweet though. Max coffee can only be found in certain regions in Japan where the people there prefer this taste. Usually, ready-to-drink coffees come in all levels of sweetness from black to Max coffee level.

Comment: Georgia uses Arebica beans  is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Georgia is the name of a popular brand of coffee drinks sold by The Coca-Cola Company. The brand is named after Coca-Cola's home state of Georgia. It was launched in 1975 by Coca-Cola (Japan) Company, a Japanese subsidiary of the company. It has since expanded to markets in Singapore, South Korea, India, Bahrain, and the United States of America. Georgia enjoys the most success in Japan, where it is the highest-grossing coffee beverage. It is also the highest-grossing beverage by Coca-Cola (Japan) Company. Max Coffee is canned coffee; It's sweet as hell.....!!!

I hope it helps.

Comment: Most of this answer is just the wiki page of Georgia Coffee, not talking about if it's sweet or not.